# How can I mount a NTFS disk under Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

I am looking to access a second HDD in my PC, it is formatted as NTFS and I the data on the second HDD cannot be replaced so I need a method that will not delete the data on the HDD.

`fdisk -l` command output about second HDD

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x60ed0890
```

I am running the following the command to try and mount the drive:

`mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb /home/colin/media`

I am getting the following error when I run the command:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a 
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

How can I mount the HDD without deleting the data currently on the HDD?

Comment: `Or the whole disk instead of a 
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)?` (hint hint - try `sdb0` or `sdb1`, do a `ls /dev/sdb*` to see which there are on the disk).

Comment: The output from `fdisk -l` shows `sda1, sda2, sda5`. How can I tell which of these relates to HDD #2?

Comment: The output is:

`/dev/sdb /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Try mounting `sdb1` instead and it should work.  `sdb` usually refers to the hard drive as a *device*, `sdb1` refers to just that physical/logical partition.  I believe `fdisk` only shows any mounted partitions as well as drives (although there may be an option to change this behaviour).

Comment: Just to clarify try mounting `sdb1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mount the logical/physical partition, and not the drive.  `sdb` refers to the hard drive as a device, whereas `sdbX` (where `X` is an integer starting from `0`) refers to the logical/physical partitions on the drive.

You can see which partitions are on the drive by doing (may need `sudo`):

```
ls /dev/sdb*
```

From the output, you should be able to determine which partition to mount.  You can then mount as you were doing, but with `sdbX` instead (e.g. assume the partition is `sdb1`, and may need `sudo`):

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /home/colin/media
```